# Como imprimir desde Java utilizando una impresa de Tickets Epson TM-U220D?

Tags: java

Imprimir un ticket desde Java utilizando una impresora `EPSON TM-U220D`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Me interesa esta pregunta pero con python xD

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/print/package-summary.html

Comment: @JavierCárdenas puedes crear una nueva pregunta y referenciarlo si te da flojera escribir mucho

Answer (score 2):

El código es muy similar al que se usa en todas las impresoras con Java, el sistema operativo se encarga de registrar los drivers y el dispositivo y entonces referencias al puerto y lo escribes mediante un flujo de Java. A diferencia de la consola, acá si debes de poner los caracteres de retorno de carro junto con el de salto de línea. Buscando un poco hallé este código en [javamexico](http://www.javamexico.org/foros/java_standard_edition/alguien_tiene_experiencia_con_impresora_de_tickets#comment-25186), para un modelo similar y como forma de hacerlo desde cero, aunque estoy casi seguro de que funcionará. Si necesitas las funciones específicas para sacarle el máximo provecho puedes encontrarlas [aquí](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/JavaPOS+USB+For+EPSON+TM-U220D+Printer+Device+Service).
El software más reciente para epson lo puedes hallar [aquí](https://www.epson-pos.com/).

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class MainClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("COM4:");

PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
String s = "PROBANDO ";

int i, len = s.length();

for (i = 0; len > 80; i += 80) {
pw.print(s.substring(i, i + 80));
pw.print("\r\n");
len -= 80;
}

if (len > 0) {
pw.print(s.substring(i));
pw.print("\r\n");
}

pw.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
System.out.println(e);
}
}
}
```

Otra forma un poco más adecuada para imprresoras modernas es mediante la clase `PrintServiceLookup`, como te lo demuestra el [código](https://bitbucket.org/javatlacati/tpdv-restaurant/src/298073d8da718a37fbf9ab06d57f62c8865aae27/src/SistemaDeKioscos/ServicioDeImpresion.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) de mi amigo Piratlax.

Comment: FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("COM4:"); esto estaría muy bien si estuviéramos trabajando en Windows, pero cuando es Linux o Mac. ??

Comment: Nunca lo he intentado en linux, especialmente por la falta de soporte de las compañías de impresoras y escacez de drivers, pero sería algo así como new FileWriter("/dev/ttyS3"); inténtalo y nos cuentas ;)

Answer (score 0):

En linux, si tienes una impresora térmica conectada via usb entonces
debes reemplazar la linea:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("COM4:");
```

por

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("/dev/usb/lp0");
```